# How to reproduce ERROR seen by CRAN maintainer / how to add .R/Makevars

Tags: r, fortran

As part of my PhD project I have completely redesigned an early draft of my R package `quantspec`. After I uploaded the tar.gz-file I obtained via BUILD, which passed CHECK on my Windows 7 computer, using the [webform](http://xmpalantir.wu.ac.at/cransubmit/), I received an email that one of the examples in my package produced an ERROR.

I've tested my package by installing it via

```
devtools::install_github("tobiaskley/quantspec", ref="develop")
```

on different computers (> 5) that are using Windows, Linux and MacOS as operating systems, but was unable to reproduce the ERROR reported.

**EDIT**: It seems to me that I'm missing some important step when building and checking the package. In Section 4.3.6 of Writing R Extensions it says that I should `add to ~/.R/Makevars` something like (for `gfortran`)

```
FCFLAGS = -g -O2 -mtune=native -fbounds-check
FFLAGS = -g -O2 -mtune=native -fbounds-check
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Is your package on GitHub? If so, [link it to Travis-CI](https://github.com/craigcitro/r-travis) to do the build and check. You should be able to play around with settings there to reproduce any errors.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, my package is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tobiaskley/quantspec). Your comment was very helpful! I've linked the repo as you suggested. The build is running. So far I have not seen the errors that the CRAN maintainer reported. I have to read more about how to configure .travis.yml. Are suggestions to have it work like the CRAN check?

Comment: If it's really just an example throwing the error, you could just remove or replace that example :-) . I would also contact the CRAN-maintainer with the information your provided here, i.e. that you passed the  CHECK --as-cran test (and presumably that your example code ran without problems).

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: I have considered that, too. It would be a pity though, because it's one of the two main functions in my package that uses the ``rq`` function of the ``quantreg`` package, which appears to fail when running on Solaris. I've contacted Prof. Ripley who notified me about the error and asked me to fix it. He suggested that I contact the maintainer of the ``quantreg`` package. Is there a way to supress execution of examples only on Solaris?

Comment: Are you sure that the example itself is producing the error rather than the example activating an error in the actual code?  Until you know that, "fixing" the problem by deleting the example might just be hiding it.   Normally Fortran array bounds checking provides a source code line number.  What does this tell you?

Comment: @M. S. B: There is no Fortran code in my package and the error message mentions ``quantreg::rq``. So you are absolutely right. This would not fix the problem, but hide it from CHECK. The package (including all my examples and ``testthat`` unit tests) passed CHECK on my Windows 7 machine and I was able to run it on Linux and Mac computers.

Comment: It seems that the way I'm using this (imported) function in the example produces the error. I was still not able to reproduce it and only have the part of the log file the CRAN maintainer (Prof. Ripley) forwarded to me. There is no source code line number. I'm considering to install a VM with OpenSolaris; I still don't know what to do next.

Comment: I've added the question about how to check my package again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to reproduce the error.

For some reason, on all systems (> 5) I have used to test my package, checking of the array bounds was turned off. It can be switched on by `options(CBoundsCheck = TRUE)` or via an environment variable `R_C_BOUNDS_CHECK=yes`.